# Java: BufferedImage from raw BMP file format data

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage, bmp

I've got BMP file's raw pixels table in `byte[]`, it's structure is:

```
(b g r) (b g r) ... (b g r) padding
...  
(b g r) (b g r) ... (b g r) padding
```

Where r, g, b are byte each, padding is to round row length up to a multiple of 4 bytes.

So, how can I create new `BufferedImage` from this raw data without copying, just using this raw data? I took a look at creating `BufferedImage` from `DataBuffer`, but I just didn't get it. Unfortunately `ImageIO` is not allowed in my situation.

Comment: Why don't you want to copy it?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for [this code](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip43.html?page=2) or something similar. It reads 24-bit BMP images and handles padding.